# Definitions for almost-simple algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

In J.S. Milne's book Algebraic Groups (2017), he defines an almost-simple algebraic group as follows:

1. An algebraic group over $k$ is **almost-simple** if it is semisimple and noncommutative, and every proper normal algebraic subgroup is finite.

He later changed this definition on 2022 to:

2. An algebraic group $G$ over $k$ is **almost-simple** if it is semisimple and noncommutative, and its only smooth connected normal subgroups are $G$ and $e$.

If we assume $k$ to be of characteristic 0 both definitions should be equivalent, since very algebraic group is smooth for this characteristic. That 1 implies 2 is obvious. For the other direction: isn't it possible for $G$ to contain some infinite but not connected normal subgroup?

I have recently started studying algebraic groups, so I am probably missing something.

Comment: Milne has a list of [Errata/addenda](https://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/iagerrata.html), where he has some remarks on almost-simple algebraic groups. You could check what he means.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I obtained the second definition precisely from his list of errata for his book's 2017 edition. I have also checked this one, but it does not seem to reveal much more

Comment: He says about amost-simple: "Need to rethink the definitions 19.7 and 19.8." - what are these definitions?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Those are the definitions for almost-simple/simple and pseudo-simple

Answer (score 0):

Assume $G$ has an infinite algebraic subgroup $H_0$ that is not connected.

For smooth algebraic groups (every algebraic group, since we are working on characteristic 0), we know being connected is equivalent to not having any proper algebraic group of finite index. As such, $H_0$ does contain some normal $H_1$ such that $H_0/H_1$ is finite. This is true because every single one of our algebraic groups is smooth, and in such conditions $(H_0)^\text{o}$ (which is normal) is of finite index, and if $(H_0)^\text{o}$ was trivial then $(H_0)^\text{dev}$ would contain it and be of finite index too, and so either we take $H_1=(H_0)^\text{dev}$ (if it is nontrivial) or take $H_1$ to be any proper algebraic subgroup of $H_0$ (since if $(H_0)^\text{dev}$ is trivial then $H_0$ is commutative).

Since $\dim H_0= \dim H_1 + \dim (H_0/H_1)=\dim H_1$, our $H_1$ cannot be finite. If it was connected, then it would be trivial by (2.) and we would have a contradiction (namely $H_0$ would be connected), so it must be not connected and contain some normal $H_2$ of finite index.

Iterating this process we get a descending sequence $H_0\supsetneq H_1 \supsetneq H_2...$, but every algebraic group, being of finite type over a field, is Noetherian, so this is not possible.